# how to convert int to LPARAM c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, type-conversion

Here is what I have tried. It builds and runs fine but prints blank.

function:

```
void wmessage(LPARAM msg, HWND hwnd)
{
    SendMessage(hwnd,
                WM_SETTEXT,
                NULL,
                msg);
}
```

usage:

```
//wmessage((LPARAM)"Not logged in22", noEdit); //prints
//wmessage((LPARAM)(t - clock()), noEdit); //prints blank
//wmessage((LPARAM)(555), noEdit); //prints blank
int num= (t - clock()); // t is a clock_t variable 
wmessage((LPARAM)num, noEdit); //prints blank
```

So i searched but I cant seem to find any mention of how to do this.

The purpose is for this textbox to print a time in seconds as it counts down, so it needs to be an int

Comment: If `t` is `clock_t` I'd recommend to also declare `num` as `clock_t`, as you might lose information otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WM_SETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) expects `lParam` to point to a `0`-terminated character array. Placing an integer in there does not make sense.

From `WM_SETTEXT`'s documentation as linked above:

> **lParam**
>
> A pointer to a null-terminated string that is the window text.

To have the text set to "555" you might like to do like so

```
char * txt = "555";
wmessage((LPARAM) txt, <some window handle>);
```

---

If you have a numerical variable to set as text, convert it to a text representation that you like. There are several ways to do this. Using `sprintf()` is the most flexible approach:

```
#include <time.h> /* for clock_t, clock() */
#include <stdio.h> /* for sprintf() */

clock_t t = <some value>;
clock_t num = (t - clock());
char buffer [16] = "";
sprintf(buffer, "%ld", num); 
wmessage((LPARAM) buffer, <some window handle>);
```

---

*<sup>It should noted that this answer's examples do not compile in a unicode environment.</sup>*

Comment: you seem to misunderstand. i only put int 555 for a test. the int I need to input in there will be taken from a (clock_t t - clock());

Comment: So convert the `clock_t` integer variable to a character representation and pass the address of the latter.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, for an exmaple how to convert an integer into a possible character representation, which in turn could be sent along a `WM_SETTEXT` message.

Comment: i seem to have figured it out while i was waiting, although what i did is almost the same as you, but i used itoa instead

Comment: @user1397417: As already mentioned in my comment to your question: I strongly recommend to **not** use `int`s to store `clock()` results. Using `itoa` you does so implicitly, as the value passed to the function will be converted to `int` which makes the value loose significant bits. Use `ltoa` as `clock_t` is `long`.

Comment: This code silently fails when building it as UNICODE. `char` needs to be replaced with `TCHAR`, `sprintf` should be `_stprintf` and the string literals `""` and `"%ld"` must be wrapped in a `_T` macro: `_T("%ld")`. Since the original code uses `SendMessage` it will expand to either `SendMessageA` or `SendMessageW` depending on preprocessor symbols.

Comment: @IInspectable: You are correct. However in the question's context I feel this issue isn't of primary importance.

Comment: It is important. If the project is changed to UNICODE it will still compile without any problems, it will even run. But only to display funny characters. The note you added is even more misleading. The code will **compile** and **run** just fine.

Answer (score 1):

LPARAM is a supposed to be an address of null-terminated char array, not a number. You would like to convert your representation into such an array. Possible methods for such are:

- Use [`std::sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) to convert int to char array and then pass a char array.
- Use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) or [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert it to `std::string` and then use `c_str()` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
LPARAM myLParam;
int myInt;
myLParam = (LPARAM) myInt; // This where the int is converted to the LPARAM
```